# Getting null parameter in apex controller from lightning controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I am not able to pass the parameter from lightning controller to apex controller. In below apex controller "accNo" is null where as in lightning controller I am getting value of accountNumber. Don't know whats wrong in my code. Please help.

Apex Controller

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Banking__c searchAccountApex(String accNo){
       system.debug(accNo);
       Banking__c searchbank = [select Account_Name__c,Balance__c, from banking__c where name = :accNo ];  // Getting accNo null
       return searchbank;
     }
```

Component

```xml
<aura:component controller="Bank_Controller">
<aura:attribute name="AccountNumber" type="String" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Banking__c" default="{'sobjectType':'Banking__c', 'Account_Name__c':'','Deposit_Amount__c':''}"/>
<aura:attribute name="searchResult" type="boolean" default="false" />
<ui:inputNumber label="Account Number" aura:Id="accountNumber1" value="{!v.AccountNumber}" class="Account_Number__c"  />
<ui:button label="search" press="{!c.searchAccount}" /> <br></br>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.searchResult}">
    Account Name    : <ui:outputText value="{!v.record.Account_Name__c}"  />  <br></br>
    Account number  : <ui:outputText value="{!v.record.name}" /> <br></br>  
    Account Balance : <ui:outputCurrency value="{!v.record.Balance__c}" />  <br></br>
</aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

JavaScript Controller

```jabascript
({
searchAccount : function(component, event, helper) {
     var accountNumberComponent=component.find("accountNumber1");
    var accountNumber = accountNumberComponent.get("v.value");
    console.log(accountNumber);    // getting account number using component.find method
    console.log(component.get("v.AccountNumber"));     // getting account number directly from accoountNumber Attributr
    var action = component.get("c.searchAccountApex");
    action.setParams({
        accNo : component.get("v.AccountNumber")    // Here when if I pass "AccountNumber" attribute, it is not getting passed. getting null in apex controller. 
    });
    action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        if(response.getState()==="SUCCESS"){
            component.set("v.record",response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.searchResult",true);
            
        } 
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    
}
})
```

Comment: I just tried your code and I am getting correct value in the apex controller. Did you add a `System.debug` in the apex method and checked the value of `accNo`?

Comment: yes  I checked twice. Its null. I don't know whats the problem and the strange thing is that if i pass a sObject (i.e "record" attribute) it is getting passed but if I pass other variables("accountNumber" variable) ,they are getting null in apex controller.

Comment: I tried too... It's alright. works as expected

Comment: Let me check once again

Comment: I am still getting null value.

Comment: I am assuming the variables name that you are using in server the parameter there is case sensitivity issues with it

Comment: No. It's given in code. It's "accNo"

Comment: I am still struggling. Can anyone please advise

Comment: can you assign this to a variable component.get("v.AccountNumber")  and pass that param into the server call. ALso if you assign it to a variable and do a console.log does it return value?

Comment: I tried that to. I am getting value in javascript but not in apex

Comment: I am sure your code had no problem from the beginning. I faced similar issues multiple times with Aura (very hard to replicate too sometimes) and every time it has been a caching problem (Javascript !!!) and you simply can't convince people who aren't familiar, that it "suddenly" started working on its own ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its very strange, I created a new component and copied code from old component and now its working. I think problem was something else, not in the code. Thank You guys for your help. I really appreciate.

Comment: This is happening with me as well. I can create a component I guess but wanted to know the root cause, if anyone is aware.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me

Comment: No. Still don't know exactly what was the root cause but never faced this issue again.

Comment: Just from reading the up-voted answers on here I would suggest it is a bug with cookeis, wouldn't surprise me if creating a new component would result in it having it's own cookie information, and so creating a new one is bascially the same as clearing them.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem. I already had 2 parameters and wanted to add 3rd, but it was always null or internal server error, no matter what i did.
So in act of desperation I have cleared cookies for the site and it worked.

So if anybody else has this problem again - clear your cookies!

Comment: Clearing cookies solved this issue 100%